# Problem with nested RecyclerView + ItemDecorator + DiffUtil

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-viewholder, android-diffutils

I have a problem with refreshing nested recyclerview with DiffResult. I have a parents list and each parent has children list. When I want to refresh whole list then I calculate DiffResult of parents list and DiffResult of children for each parent.

```
class Child {
  String id;
  String name;
  boolean highlighted;
}

class Parent {
  String id;
  String name;
  List<Child> children;
  DiffUtil.DiffResult result;
}
```

Of course I dispatch results to each adapter, bind items etc. But there is a problem with rendering proper state for each child view.

For example:
Step 1 (none highlighted):

```
{
  parents: {
    "0": {
      "name": "parent1",
      "children": {
        "0": {
           "name": "child1",
           "highlighted": false,
        },
        "1": {
           "name": "child1",
           "highlighted": false,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result on the screen:

```
<RecyclerView>
  <ParentView>
    <RecyclerView>
      <ChildView/> //not highlighted
      <ChildView/> //not highlighted
    </RecyclerView/>
  </ParentView/>
</RecyclerView>
```

It's ok.

Step 2 (only first child highlighted):

```
{
  parents: {
    "0": {  //areItemsTheSame: true, areContentsTheSame: false
      "name": "parent1",
      "children": {
        "0": { //areItemsTheSame: true, areContentsTheSame: false
           "name": "child1",
           "highlighted": true, //changed
        },
        "1": { //areItemsTheSame: true, areContentsTheSame: true
           "name": "child1",
           "highlighted": false,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result on the screen (only first child view highlighted):

```
<RecyclerView>
  <ParentView>
    <RecyclerView>
      <ChildView/> //highlighted
      <ChildView/> //not highlighted
    </RecyclerView/>
  </ParentView/>
</RecyclerView>
```

It's ok. But step 3 (**both highlighted**):

```
{
  parents: {
    "0": {  //areItemsTheSame: true, areContentsTheSame: false
      "name": "parent1",
      "children": {
        "0": { //areItemsTheSame: true, areContentsTheSame: true
           "name": "child1",
           "highlighted": true,
        },
        "1": { //areItemsTheSame: true, areContentsTheSame: false
           "name": "child1",
           "highlighted": true, //changed
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result on the screen (**BUG: Only second child highlighted!**):

```
<RecyclerView>
  <ParentView>
    <RecyclerView>
      <ChildView/> //not highlighted
      <ChildView/> //highlighted
    </RecyclerView/>
  </ParentView/>
</RecyclerView>
```

RecyclerView "reset" all views and render only "highlighted" view only for second child.

But: I can avoid this behavior and get it works properly when I set `parentRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null)` and `childRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null)`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, recyclerview created new viewholder becuase a new one was necessary to animate. To prevent it you have to define a payload for DiffResult.